# How to draw two lines in a single graph with MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library in my project. I have two different datasets and I need to draw two seperate lines in a single LineChart graph using these datasets. Any idea how can I do this? I checked it's wiki but couldn't find out. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

All you have to do is create as many `LineDataSet` objects as you want lines. If you want 2 lines, create 2 `LineDataSet`:

```
LineData chartData = new LineData();

LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(...);
chartData.addDataSet(set1);

LineDataSet set2 = new LineDataSet(...);
chartData.addDataSet(set2);

lineChart.setData(chartData);
lineChart.invalidate();
```